# Can I decode JSON containing PHP code?

Tags: php, json, parsing, laravel-blade

Is it possible to have a JSON string containing PHP Code, and to have this string decoded?

For example, this works as it should:

```
$array = ["page", "is-home", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/"];
var_export($array); 
// array (
//   0 => 'page',
//   1 => 'is-home',
//   2 => false,
// )
```

This, does not work:

```
$json = '["page", "is-home", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/"]';
$array = json_decode($json); // returns NULL
echo json_last_error_msg(); // Syntax error
```

The second example will only work if **$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/"** is removed from the json string.

Is there a way to parse this string using json_decode, and if not, are there alternative methods to accomplish this?

Many thanks!

**UPDATE**

The **$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/"** has to be parsed. I am trying to extend Blade Templating so that I can implement parsed functions such as this:

```
@add-request('page', 'is-home', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/')
```

**UPDATE #2**

To try to simplify the matter, I need to turn a string into an object.

```
$str = '["page", "is-home", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/"]'; // this is obtained by parsing the top blade extension (not important how)
```

From the string I need the following array:

```
$array = ["page", "is-home", true / false ]
```

Keep in mind that the original string can contain theoretically any PHP object for one of the JSON values.

Comment: The second example does no seem like valid JSON syntax so it shouldn't be decoded. You could (but please, don't do it) enclose everything in string markup and then eval it (don't do it, please, don't).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am determined to find another way and not to use eval, even if it means parsing the string myself. Thanks!

Comment: What is it that you're **actually** trying to do?

Comment: Ok, your second update cleared it up. I think the json functions are not what you should be looking for. What you have is not a valid json-string, and thus cannot be parsed as such. And even if it could, the php portion would still not be evaluated. Your only option is to evaluate the string as php code, either by hand or by eval (including all it's problems).

Comment: @Yoshi, thanks. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Not really because all options are hard or potentially insecure. I think it would be best, if in any way possible, to have the string in it's evaluated (or final) form even before you start handling it. Though this might as well be impossible to achieve.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a sane, supported way to do whatever it is you want to do there that does not involve strings or JSON or `eval`. But I'm not sure what it is you want to do exactly and I don't know Blade templates at all. Just understand this: you're likely approaching the whole thing wrong.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the input. It's fine if you do not know Blade. I am trying to convert a string to an array object. Please see Update #2. If I am approaching it wrong, please let me know why. Thanks!

Comment: Take three steps back. What exactly are you trying to do? Not converting arrays or anything. What's the end goal that you want to accomplish by doing all that? I'm looking for some explanation at the altitude of "add a tag in Blade based on the current URL", or something along those lines.

Comment: I am trying to hide back-end logic from front-end developers by introducing an easy-to-read syntax on the front end that is parsed into PHP code (the concept is called Templating - code is parsed once and then cached).

For example:
<meta name="description" content="@request('meta-data', 'description')"> 
and 
@add-request('meta-data', 'description', $description )

Comment: @deceze Does it make sense now?

Comment: Sort of, but I have no answer for how to best do this in Blade. I'd suggest you post a new question with this kind of high-level explanation of your goal and have someone explain to you the idiomatic way to do that in Blade.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using a variable in your string which is not parsed. In addition, `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/"` returns `false`. Boolean `false` will be converted to an empty string if it is concatenated to a string.

You should rewrite your code to something like this:

```
// Is the request URI equal to "/"?
$reqUriTest = ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/");

// If boolean false is converted to a string, it will become an empty string.
// So we need to explicitly use values "true" or "false".
$reqUriStr = ($reqUriTest ? "true" : "false");

// Now we can insert $reqUriStr into the JSON string.
$json = '["page", "is-home", '.$reqUriStr.']';
$array = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code has to be parsed and I cannot use this

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track, but instead of trying to "simulate" a decode by putting single-quotes, why not (for your proof of concept) first ENCODE, then 'echo' / 'print' the value that it returns, and then DECODE to see what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `json_encode()` to obtain json string??

```
// create json string by json_encode() from array
$json  = json_encode([
    "page",
    "is-home",
    $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/"
]);
// decode the encoded string with no error, of course ....
$array = json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can clearly see in the output, your first array does not contain any PHP at all.

```
$array = ["page", "is-home", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/"];
```

automatically fills `$array[2]` with the boolean `false`, not with PHP code.

So, let's assume you can't do such a calculation on the client (in fact, you can do this calculation in javascript as well). So you would have to send it to the server as a json string (properly encoded), decode it, eval it, and post the result back into the array.

```
$json = '["page", "is-home", "$_SERVER[\"REQUEST_URI\"] == \"/\""]';
$array = json_decode($json);
$array[2]=eval($array[2]);
```

**But please don't do this! It is a big security hole.**

Instead, feel free to ask a new question as to how *you can do this calculation in javascript as well*.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is indeed a possible option which I am trying to avoid. Please see my most recent update.

Comment: If you want to parse arbitrary expressions, there's no better way than eval. If you need a small fixed subset of expressions, you could use keywords and regexps. So, if you only want to allow checking server vars for equality, you can check whether the string matches `\{([A-Z_]*)==([A-Za-z0-9]*)\}` and if it does, replace it with `$_SERVER[\\1]==\\2` (sorry, I am bad at regexps, but I just hope you get the idea). Then a user could give the string `{REQUEST_URI==\}` and you parse it. BBCODE works this way.

Comment: Makes sense, I will consider this. Seems to be the best option for now.

Comment: Wish I could up vote you but it seems I don't have the required 15 points of reputation yet :p

Answer (score 0):

For your case you could do:

```
$is_home = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/";
$json = '["page", "is-home", '. $is_home .']';
$array = json_decode($json);
```